# How can I pass a pasted character object into a POST command in R

Tags: r, curl, httr, zyte

I need to iterate through a series of webpages using Zyte (a rotating proxy service). I used a curl converter to convert Zyte's instructions to an R friendly command. Unfortunately, when I try to paste the webpage into the full body of instructions I get a status 400. I'm not sure exactly what is wrong here. When I look at the output from the paste object it's exactly the same as what the curl converter specifies and what works without the paste complication. I've tried wrapping data in eval(), that doesn't seem to help.

```
headers = c(
  `Content-Type` = "application/json"
)

data = paste0("'",'{ \n "url": ',link.vec[i],'\n  }',"'",sep="")
  
list_html.list[[i]] <- httr::POST(url = "https://api.zyte.com/v1/extract", httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data, httr::authenticate("SPM-KEY", ""))
```

This is what the curl converter specifies:

```
headers = c(
  `Content-Type` = "application/json"
)

data = '{ \n "url": "https://denver.craigslist.org/search/cta?bundleDuplicates=1&min_price=1000&postal=80003&purveyor=owner&search_distance=100#search=1~gallery~29~0"\n  }'

res <- httr::POST(url = "https://api.zyte.com/v1/extract", httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data, httr::authenticate("SPM-KEY", ""))
```

Comment: Both `I` and `link_vec` are undefined in your code snippet, which also does not indicate how you have implemented the iteration. It’s difficult to help…

Comment: Is the code from curlconverter functional or do you get 4xx with that too?

Comment: the code from curlconverter is functional. After messing with this for a while longer I found out that I was pasting a comma in the wrong place. derp. it's working great now.

Comment: @wjb_hwe , curlconverter can point you in the right direction, but you should also check `?httr::POST()` i.e. you really don't need to craft JSON strings manually.  You can use `jsonlite::toJSON(list(url = "https://something"), auto_unbox = TRUE)` for JSON string or just  use `POST(url = "https://httpbin.org/post", body = list(url = "https://something"), encode = "json")`